# How I can remove old items from list<> for the new run of application

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my page I upload files and then save them in the database. And I have 2 buttons; one for upload and another one for save.
When I upload files I keep them in variable

```
public static List<upload> files = new List<upload>();
```

And I have added below code to upload button click:

```
files.Add(new upload(FileName,contenttype,bytes));
```

Now when press save button for saving to database

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    ProjDocAttach prjd = new ProjDocAttach();
    prjd.ProjDocID = _Projectid;

    prjd.Data = file.FileBytes;
    prjd.FileName = file.Name;
    prjd.ContentType = file.Filetype;

    _DataContext.ProjDocAttaches.InsertOnSubmit(prjd);
    _DataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

When this is the first time I run I have no problem but if it is second or more all the old uploaded files in the previous runs will be added to database.

Please help how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use static variables in web applications.

Comment: Don't use `static` mutable state in ASP.Net.  It is guaranteed to break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
files.Clear(); 
files.Add(new upload(FileName,contenttype,bytes));
```

Comment: Even funnier things will happen when two requests will run this code simultaneously.